# When in Explore window of vim, window navigation mapping <C-l> stops working

Tags: vim, key-bindings, netrw

I use the following vimrc configuration to navigate between panes:

```
" easier window navigation
nnoremap <C-j> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-k> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-l> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-h> <C-W><C-H>
```

This works fine with the exception when I'm in a `:Explore` window to do some file exploration.

All bindings besides `<C-l>` still work. But trying to navigate to the right with `<C-l>` stops working. I than have to use `<C-W><C-l>` to get out of the pane.

What do I possibly have to add or deactivate to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in `:help netrw-browse-maps`, the Netrw buffer has its own buffer-local mapping to `<C-l>` that overrides yours.

You can override Netrw's mapping with `:help netrw-usermaps` but it is at the cost of losing the ability to refresh the listing:

```
let g:Netrw_UserMaps = [["<C-l>","MoveCursorToWindowOnTheRight"]]
function! MoveCursorToWindowOnTheRight(islocal)
    return "wincmd l"
endfunction
```

Comment: Since I do exactly as mentioned in the documentation "One may also
refresh a local directory by using ':e .'" (I do have a separate mapping for that), the mentioned solution fixes the problem for me without a loss in perceived functionality.